Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render
When I deploy my application to vercel, below error occurs.
production An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive detail

It only happens in the live website, not on Vercel Preview or local.
page.tsx
...
const DeviceCardGroup = dynamic(() => import("./DeviceCardGroup"), {
  ssr: false,
});

export default async function Page() {
  const config =
    await axiosInstance.get(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/xxxx`,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken?.value,
        },
      }
    );

  return (<DeviceCardGroup/>);
}

DeviceCardGroup
function DeviceCardGroup() {
     const { deviceList } = useGetDeviceList();
}

useGetDeviceList
...

export default function useGetDeviceList() {
  const [deviceList, setDeviceList] = useState<Device[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getDevicesData() {
      if (!shouldFetch) return;

      const accessToken = getAccessToken();
      const raw = await fetch(`/api/rpc/get-devices`, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "X-Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });
      const { devices } = await raw.json();
      setDeviceList(devices);
    }
    getDevicesData();
  }, [deviceId, shouldFetch]);

  return { deviceList };
}


api/rpc/get-devices
...
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const { searchParams } = request.nextUrl;

  const deviceId = searchParams.get("deviceId");
  const headersList = headers();
  const XAuthorizationValue = headersList.get("x-authorization");

  const response: AxiosResponse<ApiResponse> = await axiosInstance.post(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/rpc/device`,
    {
      method: "getDevices",
    },
    {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-Authorization": XAuthorizationValue,
      },
    }
  );

  const {
    data: { devices },
  } = response;

  const sanitizedDevices: Device[] = devices.map(
    ({ ipaddr, swVersion, ...rest }) => rest
  );

  return Response.json({ devices: sanitizedDevices });
}


I tried to import the component without dynamic import, but still doesn’t work. I am wondering if it's related to calling route handler in server components. I use next build

i think the error not from dynamic import. i think its from your fetch data implementation, maybe when you fetch data from api, there is an event or hook which cause that error. maybe you can change your logic to client side with "use client" at the top of file.i hope my resolution can help you 
source :
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44463
